# Training Japanese vineberry

Tags: pruning, fruits, berries, soft-fruit

**Context**
I have been growing this Japanese Wineberry (*Rubus phoenicolasius*) for 2 years, and it was already 2 years old when I bought it. See annotated image below.
I have usually pruned it by removing the "old wood" canes in late summer, after they have fruited, and training the "new wood" ones onto the fence support that you see, to prepare them for the fruit that comes on then in the following year. The fruiting shoots of the plant come off the main cane in early spring, and flower in early summer.

**Question**: I would like to train the plant into a permanent frame (a bit like you would do with climbing roses onto a wall); this would create a set of permanent canes, which become increasingly "woodier". Would fruiting still happen from side shoots of these main branches? Will the tips still grow and allow me to shape these canes even further? Will this weaken or reduce the new canes? Should I still keep these?

[image]